# Clear Categories in Outlook 2003

Tags: outlook

Outlook 2007 automatically strips categories from incoming email.

Outlook 2003 does not do this, forcing the recipient to use the senders categories.

Is there a way to either:
Force Outlook 2003 to remove the categories (can't do it via Rules and Alerts) on incoming email.
OR
Force both Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2003 to remove categories before sending?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 2):

Try setting up a rule to run a script:

```
Sub RemoveCategories(MyMail As MailItem)
  Dim strID As String
  Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

  strID = MyMail.EntryID
  Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
  objMail.Categories = ""
  objMail.Save

  Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is based on [this article](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62).

Comment: That's where I've been trying to go, but the objMail.Categories = "" doesn't clear the categories.  I've put other logic in there (objMail.Subject = "Test") to make sure the script is running, and it is.  There aren't any attributes past objMail.Categories.